# Difference between bare except and specifying a specific exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I could write a simple `except` clause without writing an Exception in front of it. I mean, the last line could be like this :

```
except:
  print('Hit an exception other than KeyError or NameError!')
```

What is the point of writing `Exception` in front of an `except` clause?

```
try:
    discounted_price(instrument, discount)
except KeyError:
    print("There is a keyerror in your code")
except NameError:
    print('There is a TypeError in your code')
except Exception:
    print('an exception occured')
```

I tried writing an `except` clause without an Exception and it worked the same.

I know the point of catching specific errors. If I want to ask more clearly, what is the difference between these two clauses :

```
except Exception:
    print('an exception occured')

except :
    print('an exception occured')
```

Comment: Please do not substantially edit the question after getting answers already, instead ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare expect

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

or catching any exception whatsoever

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    pass
```

are bad practice, because you can be hiding bug or be interfering with the normal procedure of the program.

You should only catch exception that you know how to handle, everything else you should let it propagate.

For some example:

Hide bug: it can hide some typo in your code as Caridorc example show making you think that you had a problem different than the real problem

Interfering with the normal procedure: you can make it an unexpectedly unkillable program or get in the way of the normal procedure of the program by discarding an exception that another part of the code was expecting.

like for example

```
while True:
    try: 
        print("running")
    except:
        print("I'm immortal muahahaha")
```

this piece of code now you can't stop with you usual control-z (control-z throw and KeyboardInterrupt exception into your program) so you now need to close the whole interpreter/kill it with the task admin just to stop it, and if this was unintended you just introduced a new bug and depending on what you're doing it can be catastrophic.

To illustrate how catastrophic it can be, consider the following hypothetical case: imagine you make so benign function for a medical device and you put something like this

```
try: 
    ...
except:
    print("some error happens")
```

now it just so happens that while you piece of code was running a HeartAttack exception was raised and your catch it all and ignore piece of code will do, well, just that, and here is the twist this device was a pacemaker... well, congratulation you just killed the poor guy.

And that is why you should only catch the exception you know how to deal with, everything else you let it pass and hope that somebody along the line know how to deal with it, like in the example above, you and your piece of code don't know how to deal with a HeartAttack, but the pacemaker do and the pacemaker was the one that call your piece of code let it deal with it...

---

for a no so extreme example consider this simple code

```
def get_number_from_user():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("write a number: "))
        except:
            print("not a valid number try again")
```

if your user was done with your program and this happens to be the thing running he/she might want to kill it with a control-z as you usually do with any program, but it will find that it doesn't work, the correct way here is to catch the error we know how to deal with in this case, namely ValueError, everything else isn't this function business

```
def get_number_from_user():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("write a number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("not a valid number try again")
```

---

You also ask about the difference between

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

and this

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    pass
```

the difference is that a bare except can catch any and all kind of exception, that in python is anything that is or inherit from BaseException that sit at the top of the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), while `except Exception` will catch only *Exception* itself or anything that inherit from it (the same apply for any particular exception you put there), this small distinction allow to make some exceptions more special than other, like the aforementioned KeyboardInterrupt that inherit from BaseException instead of Exception, and that is used to signal that the *user wants to terminate this program, so you should do so* and this distinction is made basically so new programmers don't shoot themselves in the foot when using `except Exception`

Answer (score 3):

The point of specifying the Exception is that ONLY that Exception will be caught, if you do not specify any Exception, then ALL Errors and Exceptions will be caught potentially masking bugs.

For example let's say that I want to read a file if it exists or otherwise print a message to the user, I can write:

```
try:
    with ope("example.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
except:
    print("File not found")
```

But while this code runs fine without raising any exceptions, this code will never read the file, even if it exists!!!

This is because I wrote `ope` instead of `open` and the `NameError` was caught by my bare `except`, If I write the `except` in the correct way:

```
try:
    with ope("example.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

Now I can properly debug my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/riccardo/types.py", line 4, in <module>
    with ope("example.txt", "r") as f:
NameError: name 'ope' is not defined
```

Comment: Just to add to that, by specifying each error separately, you can run specific error handling code pertaining to that error when the exception arises. If for example the file does not exist, you can print  message to that effect. If however, it fails to print because you mistyped g instead of f, you can print a message to say that the variable is not recognised ( separate code for separate error captures)

Comment: @GalodoLeste Good point, feel free to elaborate on it on it in a new answer as sadly comments may be removed at any time and are not really permanent.

Comment: Thank you guys @Caridorc. I know what you are talking about. If I want to ask it more clearly , do you see any difference between these two :

except Exception:
    print('an exception occured')
except :
    print('an exception occured')

Comment: @Amir.the.explorer that is a different question. Feel free to ask a new question about it (comments may be deleted at any time, so questions and answers must be written to keep the content enriching over time)

Comment: Amir: see my additional answer below (I have provided two explaining different aspects)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer provided by @Caridorc, by specifying each error separately, you can run specific error handling code pertaining to that error when the exception arises. If for example the file does not exist, you can print message to that effect. If however, it fails to print because you mistyped g instead of f, you can print a message to say that the variable is not recognised ( separate code for separate error captures). For exmple:

```
g = 100 # Unrelated variable declared previously
try:
    with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
        x=print(f.read())

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
except AttributeError:
    print("Reading wrong variable")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unknown Error", e)
```

Note also the last exception  `except Exception as e:`. This is the same as just `except:` but allows you to handle all other errors that do not fit onto previous captures and retrieve e - the error message that is generated by compiler. There is effectively no difference between `except:` and `except Exception:` in terms of execution

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code:

```
a = 5
b = 0
x = a / b
```

Executing this will alert you to the fact that you have attempted to divide a float by zero but it will crash your code.

Now consider:

```
a = 5
b = 0
try:
    x = a / b
except: # or 'except Exception:'
    print("An exception was raised")
```

This will raise an exception that is handled by printing a message that an error occurred. You code will not crash but you do not know how to properly handle the code because you do not know what the exception was, just that one occurred.

Now consider:

```
a = 5
b = 0
try:
    x = a / b
except Exception as e:
    print("An exception was raised, generating error", e)
```

Now your code does not crash. Is handled and you know what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of writing "Exception" in front of an except clause is to catch all possible exceptions that can occur in the code. By specifying "Exception", you are telling the interpreter to handle any type of exception that might be raised. The more specific the exception specified in the except clause, the more targeted the handling of the exception can be. For example, if you only want to handle "KeyError" exceptions, you can specify that explicitly in the except clause, as in the first example.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers . I know the point of catching specific errors. If I want to ask more clearly , what is the difference between two clauses :

except Exception:
    print('an exception occured')

except :
    print('an exception occured')